# Phonegap source control gotchas?

Tags: ios, git, cordova

I'll be working in a team doing phonegap applications for the first time.

For a super simple boilerplate app shared by a team of 3, should I be including the entire project (i.e. all the directories):

```
app
--merges
--platforms
--plugins
--www
```

Having had user specific issues with conflicts which arise with iOS builds (and I'm assuming android builds), should I be adding the `platforms` directory in the .gitignore? Am I correct in assuming that all builds should be done by the user and not rely on someone else's phonegap build-ed versions of the app?

Comment: For projects I have worked on my team resolved to only include the www and merges folders. We ran into too many issues trying to add platforms and plugins

Comment: What is the merges folder for exactly?

Comment: If you have an asset that needs to be different for various platforms you save the various versions in platform folders in there. so say you have a different CSS file for iOS vs Android you would create two CSS files with same name and save them to /merges/ios/www/css/style.css and /merges/android/www/css/style.css. This will save each file to the correct platform build and then in your code you just refernce /css/style.css and don't need to do your own check for platforms

Comment: Thank you! So how does your .gitignore file look?

Comment: .cordova/*
.idea/*
plugins/*
platforms/*

Answer (score 0):

In my project we only commit the www folder and a windows batch file (We develop on Windows) that is the responsable for install automatically each plugin that the app needs.

When a new plugin is added, we add a new entry to that file.

When a new developer wants to make his developt enviroment with the app, him creates a new proyect and imports the www folder. After that, he runs the local build command and later runs the custom porject plugin file.