# Cordova - VCS and project organisation

Tags: cordova

We are having some problems with the VCS organisation of our Cordova project. We've organised our project according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706954/phonegap-source-control-gotchas) SO answer. Our current .gitignore:

```
.cordova/*
plugins/*
platforms/*
```

After doing some work on the project I notices that it is sometimes necessary to modify the built app in the `platforms/` folder, e.g. [changing the iOS icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820492/how-to-add-app-icon-within-phonegap-projects). Now my questions is what is the best way to manage this? Should we use two separate repositories (or more), one for the `app/www/` folder and then one each for `app/platforms/*os*`? Or put all files in one repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i keep plugins, .cordova and platforms underversion control. and have only one repository for a phonegap project.

what I put in ignore list is www folders inside each platforms, the paltforms bin folders and anything that's not in the platform folder after you clean the platform (launch the platforms/platformname/cordova/clean script)

Comment: QuickFix is this still relevant today?

Comment: Still what I do but I think you could just have config.xml and www/hooks/merges folders in version control if you save the plugins in config.xml. I think platforms folder can be safely ignored (or maybe just keep platforms.json if you want to be sure everyone has the same version of the platform?)